# Are accessors / mutators auto-defined in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

In the section on handling Java Beans with Groovy of *Groovy In Action*, I found this script (slightly modified):

```
class Book{
  String title
}
def groovyBook = new Book()
// explicit way
groovyBook.setTitle('What the heck, really ?')
println groovyBook.getTitle()
// short-hand way
groovyBook.title = 'I am so confused'
println groovyBook.title
```

There are no such methods in the class `Book` so how does that work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they are auto defined and calling `book.title` is actually calling `book.getTitle()`

See http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Beans

You can see this in action with the following script:

```
def debug( clazz ) {
    println '----'
    clazz.metaClass.methods.findAll { it.name.endsWith( 'Name' ) || it.name.endsWith( 'Age' ) }.each { println it }
}

class A {
    String name
    int age
}
debug( A )
// Prints
// public int A.getAge()
// public java.lang.String A.getName()
// public void A.setAge(int)
// public void A.setName(java.lang.String)

// Make name final
class B {
    final String name
    int age
}
debug( B )
// Prints
// public int B.getAge()
// public java.lang.String B.getName()
// public void B.setAge(int)

// Make name private
class C {
    private String name
    int age
}
debug( C )
// Prints
// public int C.getAge()
// public void C.setAge(int)

// Try protected
class D {
    protected String name
    int age
}
debug( D )
// Prints
// public int D.getAge()
// public void D.setAge(int)

// And public?
class E {
    public String name
    int age
}
debug( E )
// Prints
// public int E.getAge()
// public void E.setAge(int)
```

Comment: So, for every variable that you put into your class there is an auto-generated **`public`** accessor / mutator ?

Comment: I believe unless it's private, yes

Comment: well, I have a long way to go in Groovy. methods are always public and classes can have any of the modifiers available in Java ? =)

Comment: Yes, but package scope can only be specified through the `@PackageScope` annotation

Answer (score 2):

Several notes:

1. For all property fields(public ones only), there are autogenerated accesors.
2. Default visibility is public. So, you should use private/protected keyword to restrict accessor generation.
3. Inside an accessor there is direct field access. like `this.@title`
4. Inside a constructor you have direct access to! This may be unexpected.
5. For boolean values there are two getters with `is` and `get` prefixes.
6. Each method with such prefixes, even java ones are treated as accessor, and can be referenced in groovy using short syntax.
7. But sometimes, if you have ambiguous call there may be class cast exception.

Example code for 4-th point.

```
class A{
   private int i = 0;
   A(){
     i = 4
     println("Constructor has direct access. i = $i")
   }
   void setI(int val) { i = val; println("i is set to $i"); } 
   int getI(){i}
  }

def a = new A() // Constructor has direct access. i = 4
a.i = 5 // i is set to 5
println a.i // 5
```

​
4-th note is important, if you have some logic in accessor, and want it to be applied every time you call it. So in constructor you should explicit call `setI()` method!

Example for 7

```
class A{
   private int i = 0;
   void setI(String val) { println("String version.")}
   void setI(int val) { i = val; println("i is set to $i"); } 
}

def a = new A()
a.i = 5 // i is set to 5
a.i = "1s5" // GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '1s5' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'int'
```

​
So, as I see property-like access uses first declared accessor, and don't support overloading. Maybe will be fixed later.

Answer (score 0):

Groovy generates public accessor / mutator methods for fields when and only when there is no access modifier present. For fields declared as public, private or protected no getters and setters will be created.

For fields declared as final only accessors will be created.

All that applies for static fields analogously.